# GitHub に SSH 鍵を登録したい

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-bash

YouTubeでGitの使い方を見ているのですが、その動画にはないポップアップがでてきます（赤い丸）。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

それを検索したらこのサイトがでてきました。
https://docs.github.com/ja/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

④で突っかかってしまい、そこからGit BashでEnter以外なにも入力できない状態です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

どなたかご指導お願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

英語でもメッセージをちゃんと読みましょう。
SSH Keyのパスフレーズを聞かれているので、（任意の）SSHに使うパスフレーズ（＝パスワード）を入力してあげて下さい。
それで次のステップに進めます

Answer (score 1):

パスフレーズを設定する手順ですが、(肩越しのセキュリティ対策として) プロンプトに文字が表示されないだけで、実際には入力したままが反映されているはずです。